# Repeater Control binding categories to details

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I'm new to repeater controls and pretty unfamiliar with them. Can someone help get me on the right    track. Im using c# asp.net. I need my repeater to populate a sidebar with category names. On category name click, a main content  div will populate category item details.

Thank you

All i have so far is populating the table with a hardcoded pk

```
 <div class="chartdisplay">
          <div id="repeater">
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater" runat="server">
          <HeaderTemplate>
              <table width="100%" style= "background-color:#cccccc; font-size: 16px">
        <tr style="background-color:#00bfbf"> <th> Item #</th> <th>  Item Description </th> <th>Pre Price</th> <th>Size</th>  </tr>                                                                                                                                         

                  </HeaderTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
           <tr>     <td> <%#Eval("Item #") %></td>
                    <td> <%#Eval("Item Description") %></td>
                    <td> <%#Eval("Pre Price") %></td>
                    <td> <%#Eval("Size") %></td>            </tr> 

                       </ItemTemplate>

                  <AlternatingItemTemplate>
         <tr style="background-color:#eeeeee">
          <td> <%#Eval("Item #") %></td>
                    <td> <%#Eval("Item Description") %></td>
                    <td> <%#Eval("Pre Price") %></td>
                    <td> <%#Eval("Size") %></td
         </tr>
      </AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate> </Table> </FooterTemplate>                          

                </asp:Repeater>
             </div>
 </div>
```

and side bar

```
  <div class="productCategoriesLabel">                                          
      <asp:Repeater ID="rptrCategories" OnItemCommand="detailsCat" runat="server">
         <ItemTemplate>
          <tr><td><%#Eval("PromoGroup") %></td></tr>

     </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:Repeater>  
  </div>
```

Comment: You can get the Idea of repeater from previous post :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398312/nested-repeaters-in-c-sharp/17398600#17398600

Comment: The only part of your question that's related to the Repeater control, is that you've mentioned you'll be using it.

Comment: The Repeater part looks good. Please change your question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how u can bind another Repeater on click.

```
 <div class="productCategoriesLabel">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptrCategories" runat="server" 
        onitemcommand="rptrCategories_ItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnGroup" CommandName="cmd" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("PromoGroup") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>

protected void rptrCategories_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "cmd")
    {
        string Group = ((LinkButton)rptrCategories.Items[e.Item.ItemIndex].FindControl("lbtnGroup")).Text;
        // DataTable dt = GroupDeatils(Group);
        detRepeter.DataSource = dt;
        detRepeter.DataBind();
    }
}
```